# Load App after parserDidEndDocument

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

I'm reading XML from internet in my `AppDelegate` inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, but the problem is my app got loaded before `parserDidEndDocument` got triggered!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    [self openXML];
    NSLog(@"loaded?"); //target
    [self.window addSubview:tabController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    NSLog(@"loaded.");
}
```

How can I hold loading the app until `parserDidEndDocument` triggered?

Moreover, how can I proceed & continue loading the app if I couldn't load the XML for any reason?

Comment: This question is about iOS, it has nothing to do with Xcode

Answer (score 0):

You are going to parse xml in app, so in any way you need to run and load you app at first :). So, if you need to perform some synchronious task in main thread then simply create an empty view with dark backround and UIActivityIndicator, bring this view to user without interactions( perhaps). When task will finished (parserDidEndDocument) just remove that view.